# How do you output information directly from EC2 to a file (such as .txt or .json)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I wanted to export the security group rules from EC2 to a type of file (such as .txt or .json). I'm using javascript/node.js to make this output. Unfortunately, I tested it to no avail.

I have developed a code the would allow me to output the security groups (rules, ingress, egress, etc.) whilst putting them into a text file. I would first load the SDK into my javascript file and set the region. Then, I create the service object before retrieving the information.

This is the code I have used for this experimentation:

```
// Load the SDK for JavaScript
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

var fs = require('fs');

// Create EC2 service object
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15'});

// Retrieve security group descriptions

ec2.describeSecurityGroups(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Failed to retrieve information", err);
    }
    var sGroups = data.SecurityGroups;
    console.log("Your input has been confirmed!", JSON.stringify(sGroups));

    fs.writeFile('AWSnodeTest.txt', sGroups, function(err, result) {
        if(err) console.log("Failed to output into file", err);
    });
});
```

When I tested the experimentation out via PowerShell, it was perfect at first. All the information from the security groups were well displayed on PowerShell. However, on the basis of:

```
fs.writeFile('AWSnodeTest.txt', sGroups, function(err, result) {
    if(err) console.log("Failed to output into file", err);
});
```

I only received the following output for the file mentioned:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

It appears that there is something wrong with that piece of code that would help me write the file. What functions do I need to retrieve the EC2 security groups into a file by way of javascript?

Comment: try with `fs.writeFile('AWSnodeTest.txt', JSON.stringify(sGroups)), function(err, result) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're passing the variable sGroups as the content to be written to the file, and not the JSON serialised string.
I've also took the liberty of adding a `return` statement in case of error ,see updated code below:

```
ec2.describeSecurityGroups(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Failed to retrieve information", err);
        return;  // Added this as there's no point in continuing.
    }
    var sGroupsJSON = JSON.stringify(data.SecurityGroups);
    console.log("Your input has been confirmed!", sGroupsJSON);

    fs.writeFile('AWSnodeTest.txt', sGroupsJSON, function(err, result) {
        if(err) console.log("Failed to output into file", err);
    });
});
```

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was a perfect way to reorganize my code, as I now know that the JSON.stringify had to be incorporated in a combined variable first. Thank you for that.